Modal Bootstrap dentro de un loop PHP o pagina dinamica
No soy buena en esto de programar pero necesito ayuda para una tarea de la universidad y mi maestra me dejo más confundida que antes.
Estoy haciendo una página de una cafetería en la sección de menú al dar clic sobre un producto se debe abrir un modal con la descripcion del producto. Ahora que manejo php cada que doy clic en un producto me aparece el modal pero siempre aparece la misma informacion para todos los productos cuando deberia ser lo contrario
--Codigo HTML--
<?php
include("COMPONENTES/conexion.php");
$seleccion_productos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria_prod='Combos'");|
while($listar_productos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seleccion_productos)) {
    ?>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-3 tarjeta">
                        <div class="row g-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <img src="images/<?php echo $listar_productos['imagen_prod'];?>" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn boton-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#id_modal">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title texto-menu"><?php echo $listar_productos['nombre_prod'];?><br><?php echo $listar_productos['precio_prod'];?></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

--Codigo MODAL--
<?php
                include("COMPONENTES/conexion.php");
                
                $seleccion_productos_modal = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria_prod='Combos'");

                while($listar_productos_modal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seleccion_productos_modal)) {
                    
                ?>
                <div class="modal fade" id="id_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="id_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog">
                        
                        <div class="modal-content">

                            <div class="modal-header popup-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="id_modalLabel"><?php echo $listar_productos_modal['nombre_prod'];?></h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="popup">
                                    <img class="popup-img" src="images/<?php echo $listar_productos_modal['imagen_prod'];?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="popup-caja">
                                    <span class="popup-text">
                                        <?php echo $listar_productos_modal['descripcion'];?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>

Adjunto foto

¿Y como lo quieres?  Así es como lo has programado al poner el while antes del modal-dialog...  Si lo pones más adentro tendras un modal con varios elementos supongo, según como lo quieras.  Por cierto, si te fijas en tu consulta MYSQL verás que siempre te apareceran todos los de la categoria, y no solo un producto. Si solo quieres ver un producto cambia la consulta para que salga solo ese.

que al dar clic aparezca uno solo y que cada que hago clic aparezca el modal con la información relacionada al producto. Perdón si no soy muy clara, programación nunca fue mi fuerte

A ver, si quieres modales distintos por producto sin usar ajax vas a tener que cambiar bastantes cosas. Para empezar, pon un contador o usa identificador de tu producto en el primer trozo de html que has puesto, y ese contador o identificador lo pones aquí: data-bs-target="#exampleModal" para que siempre sea distinto. Y luego igual debajo, subiendo el while por encima de <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal"  y haciendo que los id coindidan.  Léetelo con calma, pero es una forma de hacerlo.

ahora ya sale un solo modal pero sale la info de un solo producto

Modifica la pregunta y su descripción poniendo todo el código nuevo que tengas ahora para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes pulsar sobre [edit] para ello.

ya lo edito gracias

listo ya esta editado

No me has entendido. Donde pones data-bs-target="#id_modal" debes poner un valor único en cada pasada del while, por ejemplo el código del producto precedido de #modal_, y después, donde pones el id="id_modal" pues lo mismo, que sea algo así como id="modal_<?php echo $listar_productos_modal['codigo_unico'];?>"... donde codigo_unico puede ser el id del producto o algun campo de esa tabla que lo identifique de forma única. Y que ambos coincidan en cada pasada, claro, tanto en el data-bs-target= como en el id=.

Te he agregado una respuesta completa, a ver si te sirve y lo entiendes mejor así.

Si lo ponemos todo junto mejor, así ahorras ejecutar el mismo ciclo dos veces:
<?php
include("COMPONENTES/conexion.php");
$seleccion_productos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria_prod='Combos'");|
while($listar_productos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seleccion_productos)) {
?>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
  <div class="card mb-3 tarjeta">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $listar_productos['imagen_prod'];?>" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn boton-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_<?php echo $listar_productos['id'];?>">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title texto-menu"><?php echo $listar_productos['nombre_prod'];?><br><?php echo $listar_productos['precio_prod'];?></h5>
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_<?php echo $listar_productos['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="id_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header popup-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="id_modalLabel"><?php echo $listar_productos['nombre_prod'];?></h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="popup">
          <img class="popup-img" src="images/<?php echo $listar_productos['imagen_prod'];?>">
        </div>
        <div class="popup-caja">
          <span class="popup-text">
            <?php echo $listar_productos['descripcion'];?>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

Fíjate que hago coincidir el valor de este atributo:
data-bs-target="#modal_<?php echo $listar_productos['id'];?>"

con el id del modal:
id="modal_<?php echo $listar_productos['id'];?>"

y así, en cada pasada, se corresponderan bien y cuando pulses el botón de cada producto solo abrirá el modal que le corresponda por el id idéntico que le has puesto.
Nota: He dado por supuesto que la tabla productos tiene un campo id único, pues desconozco su estructura. Pero si no tiene ese nombre usa el que tenga que lo identifique únicamente.

ok por lo que deseas no es tan complicado tengo la consulta, si estas utilizando Bootstrap porque si es asi para no complicarte solo manda en el boton del modal el correlativo de la imagen que desea utilizar para no usar el while para recorrer todo el conjunto de datos, sino que solamente el valor que desea saber.


<button type="button" class="btn boton-modal" data-nombre_producto="<?php echo $listar_productos['nombre_prod'];?>" data-precio_produc="<?php echo $listar_productos['precio_prod'];?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                     <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title texto-menu"><br></h5>
                     </div>
                  </button>



y en la conexion a la base coloca el correlativo del producto en cuestión y de esa manera solamente llamas a ese producto en cuestion y evitas llamar a todo el catalogo.


"SELECT correlativo_producto FROM productos WHERE categoria_prod='Combos'"




Perdona, pero tu respuesta es muy imprecisa, mejor la arreglas bien o la borras, sino solo confundirás al que pregunta. Y te recomiendo que no pongas tu email en sitios web públicos sino quieres recibir spam eternamente.

Las dudas deben resolverse aquí, no a través de contacto "personalizado". Es por eso que existe [es.so]: para que sea una base de conocimientos, no para ser un "gancho" para tutoría personalizada. Además, nunca dejes datos sensibles (correo electrónico, número de teléfono) en un sitio público, donde miles de bots scrapean el sitio diariamente.

tomare en cuenta tu comentario, para mejorar mis respuestas es la primera vez que doy mi opinión y por esa razón no encontraba la manera de explicarlo de manera sencilla pero gracias. @masterguru.
